# What is a robust way to store common authentication details across Node.js projects?

Tags: node.js, authentication

At the moment I have several separate Node.js projects exposing various REST APIs.  They all connect to a common authentication source and use the same username and password.  At the moment I have this stored in JavaScript source code.  What is the proper way to do this in a production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, in production, you would expect to have the user data in a data store with a common access process. This would allow the user data to be independently managed (audits, backups, password resets, etc) as well if required.

If you can, the most robust solution would be to tie in to a specialist data store such as an Enterprise Directory (e.g. LDAP or ActiveDirectory) but if the web application is stand-alone and public you could use any of the NoSQL or SQL databases. Just remember to store the passwords securely and correctly hashed. You could use a simple external JSON file if you will only ever have a few users but this is far from ideal once you have more than 1/2 dozen or so users.

A final alternative would be to let someone else worry about the user management and allow users to log in using external services such as Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc. There are Node libraries that will do the donkey work for you. You will still want to keep some information about the users though - again, a simple data store will be fine.